# unknown custom file format reader source equals writer source?

Tags: c, file-format, hexdump

Am I correct in assuming that an obscure file format loader's c level source/abstraction that  closely corresponds to a hex dump of the original file can also be used to make the said file format construction source code from scratch in what seems to be something like bootstrapping?

Comment: Can you please clarify.  Your question is too 'obscure'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. There usually are auxiliary resources that do not need to be written out, but still have to be reconstructed by the loading function. It's hard to say anything more without knowing your specific situation.